# using iPhone as android application development, testing phone

Tags: iphone, android

Can i use my iPhone for android application development testing?

Comment: Why would you think you could possibly do this?

Comment: Because we can install android on iphone. And offcourse different versions of android. Its now easy more easy...

Comment: @cyber_wolf are you able to get it done for iphone-4 ? i'm trying this too but couldn't get it working

Answer (score 3):

By using some hacks, you can do so. But what will be the use of this? The users of your application will use it on an Android phone, not on iPhone. If you don't have an Android device, you can test your apps on emulators of different versions.

Comment: I use to test on emulators but we can use an iphone as an android device, so why not use it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it may be possible:

- http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=android+on+iphone&aq=0
- http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=how+to+install+android+on+iphone

Just try to install Android on your iPhone.

Comment: One of my friends did this once. I think it only works on iPhone 2G and 3G. Nonetheless, it is a complete hack. Not sure I would trust it to test an app that I was shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Does your iPhone run Android? Probably not, so no you can not use your iPhone to test apps that were built for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* install Android on an iPhone, but I don't know about developing.
For iPhone 2G: http://www.iphoneheat.com/2010/05/install-android-on-iphone-3g-2g-iphodroid/
3G/S: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB9e3Cb-H4I
(Nothing available for iPhone 4 yet, but it is coming soon: http://www.redmondpie.com/android-on-iphone-4)
This is still a preliminary version, and is buggy, as a lot of the drivers don't work. This could limit it from being used for Android development.